# How does ios get the color gradient of the UITextView cursor

Tags: colors, cursor, uitextview, gradient

I want to get the color gradient of the UITextView cursor from top to bottom in iOS,thanks.

Comment: How do I get the UITextView cursor object？

Comment: This question is really unclear and risks getting flagged or closed.  I'm not an iOS developer, but is this for swift or objective-c?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is for objective-c,thanks.